# How to get Key from Value in Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have defined `Enum`and `Dictionary` as below.
Now in `Dictionary`, I want to get `Key` from `Value` using `Linq`

```
enum Devices
    {
        Fan,
        Bulb,
        Mobile,
        Television
    };

Dictionary<int, Devices> dctDevices = new Dictionary<int, Devices>()
{
    {1, Devices.Fan},
    {2, Devices.Bulb},
    {3, Devices.Mobile},
    {4, Devices.Television}
};
```

I want result like below. I need concrete method named below.

```
int key = GetKeyFromValue(Devices.Bulb);
```

Please suggest me the best way to perform this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, its counter 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: maybe a question, why not `Dictionary<Devices, int>` instead? :P

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @VladiPavelka, why not use devices as key?

Comment: Btw. if you don't specify otherwise, an `enum` value basically already is an `int` value (starting with `0`). I don't know what the key should actually represent, but maybe your use case is simply: `int key = (int)value + 1;`

Comment: For device at first, I can understand but it's actual requirement. I can,t put Dictionary at first. Thank for suggestion.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate question doesn't handle the case that the value wasn't found. It works accidentially for reference type keys(because a dictionary key cannot be null)) but not for value types like here, especially if `0` was a valid key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method could look like:

```
int GetKeyFromValue(Devices device)
{
    return dctDevices.Keys
        .Where(k => dctDevices[k] == device)
        .DefaultIfEmpty( -1 ) // or whatever "not found"-value
        .First();
}
```

or a generic extension method for any type:

```
public static TKey GetKeyByBalue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TValue value, TKey notFoundKey, IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    return dict.Keys.Where(k => comparer.Equals(dict[k], value)).DefaultIfEmpty(notFoundKey).First();
}
```

Note that you should use another dictionary if you want to lookup that value often:

```
Dictionary<Devices, int> DeviceKeys = new Dictionary<Devices, int>()
{
    {Devices.Fan, 1}, // ...
};
```

Then the code becomes more efficient:

```
int key = DeviceKeys[Devices.Bulb];
```

Or create a custom class `Device` which encapsulates the ID and the `Devices` (and other things):

Comment: The "backwards" dictionary can simply be created by `var backwards = dctDevices.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);` in this case, since OP seems to expect a strict 1:1 relation. Otherwise, a similar `ToLookup` might be needed.

Comment: @Corak: the point was that he should not need to create it always, that's why i haven't shown the creation but initialized the dictionary manually once. But yes, you could initialize it also in that way.

Comment: Thanks, first answer helped me. It returns -1 if not exists.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like below:

```
dctDevices.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Value == Devices.Bulb).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Comment: It gives error when I try to search value which is not added in dictionary.

Comment: I edited my answer, can you please try again?

Comment: It always returns 0 if Key not exists. But key value as 0 can be exists.

Comment: then you can check  dctDevices.ContainsValue( Devices.Television) if it is not added you can return what you need